# How can I download a string to the browser using php? Not a text file

Tags: php, text, download, text-files

My problem is that I have a string that gets generated from database queries, timestamps, and other random things and is always different so I don't have a "file" to download. How can I use this generated string to be downloaded as a `.txt` file in the browser for the user? I know that you can download a file to the browser using headers so maybe something like this:

```
$result = 'Generated string that is different every time. 20121107160322';

header("Content-Type: text/plain");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; content=$result");
header("Content-Length: " . strlen($result));
```

Obviously this doesn't work, but I don't even know where to start.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You almost got it, you just lack to actually output the string to the browser, and also give it a filename that the browser can use to prompt the user, so do like this:

```
$result = 'Generated string that is different every time. 20121107160322';
$filename = 'result_file.txt';

header("Content-Type: text/plain");
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$filename.'"');
header("Content-Length: " . strlen($result));
echo $result;
exit;
```

Comment: Wow that's great. One question, why did you put `exit;`?

Comment: To make sure there's no more php code that run after echoing the file because if some code outputs anything out that would get into the file and cause problems.

Comment: You can skip the `exit` but make sure your following code does not output anything to the browser. Also until the php scripts does not end the browser would keep downloading the file, so better after you finish echoing the file to end the script (for that the `exit` call).

Comment: What if I WANT more code to execute after the download. Why do I have to stop all program execution at that point? Is that just not possible? I know usually when you click "download", the page does not reload. Ok, but still, what if I want to output error messages to an error log after the download? I can't do that if I exit.